# I cannot change label names in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

I am trying to change label names in `facet_grid` as well as make my data be shown in percentages. However this is not working.

```
aktivity <- ggplot(data=zaposlenost_prema_aktivnosti, 
                    mapping = aes(skrIndikator,Vrednost))

aktivity + geom_col(mapping=aes(x=skrIndikator, y=Vrednost, fill=skrIndikator)) +
        facet_grid(nPol~nVrTacka, labeller = "label_one") + 
        guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Description")) + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) + 
        labs(x="Description", y="Value", title = "Employment by activity and gender", subtitle = "Statistically obtained by a poll", caption = "source: Republic Bureau for Statistics")
```

[image: 1]